# How to subtract one from every value in a tuple in Python?

Tags: python, integer, tuples

I have a tuple created with `zip()` and I need to subtract one from each integer in the tuple.  I tried the following but apparently it only works on lists, so how would I adapt this for tuples in Python?

```
[...]
lower, upper = zip(*table)
lower[:] = [x + 1 for x in lower]
upper[:] = [x - 1 for x in upper]
holes = zip(lower[:-1], upper[1:])
```

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Big picture is I have a series of non-overlapping sorted intervals stored in `table` and I need to get the series of holes.  E.g. my intervals table could be:

```
[ 6,  7]
[ 8,  9]
[14, 18]
[23, 32]
```

And I want to compute the `holes` in between the intervals:

```
[10, 13]
[19, 22]
```

Comment: After many many reasonings helped by @gnibbler, and numerous  edits of my code, I ended up to a ultimate one. See it please, and say me what you think of it please.

Comment: @eyquem To improve your answer, I would edit out the commentary of how you reached the answer to make the answer short and sweet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generator function makes the task easy.

```
table = [(2,3),(5,6),(12,20),(21,25),(28,28),(35,48),(53,55)]

def gaps_between(intervals):
    prec = intervals[0][1] + 1
    for L,H in intervals:
        print '\nprec = %d   (L,H) = (%d,%d)' % (prec,L,H)
        print 'prec = %d <= L-1 = %d : %s' % (prec,L-1,prec<=L)
        if prec<=L-1:
            yield (prec,L-1)
        prec = H + 1
        print 'next prec = %d' % prec

holes = list(gaps_between(table))

print
print 'table =',table
print 'holes =',holes
```

In a former answer, I had used an iterator defined inside the generator.
To avoid this, I here above use a stratagem :
defining `first prec = first H = intervals[0][1]`.
Given the fact that `H>=L` for every couple (L,H) , it leads to
`first H > first L - 1` -->  `first prec > first L - 1`.
Hence the first test concerning the first interval is always False and the real process starts at the second interval.

```
prec = 3   (L,H) = (2,3)
prec = 3 <= L-1 = 1 : False
next prec = 4

prec = 4   (L,H) = (5,6)
prec = 4 <= L-1 = 4 : True
next prec = 7

prec = 7   (L,H) = (12,20)
prec = 7 <= L-1 = 11 : True
next prec = 21

prec = 21   (L,H) = (21,25)
prec = 21 <= L-1 = 20 : True
next prec = 26

prec = 26   (L,H) = (28,28)
prec = 26 <= L-1 = 27 : True
next prec = 29

prec = 29   (L,H) = (35,48)
prec = 29 <= L-1 = 34 : True
next prec = 49

prec = 49   (L,H) = (53,55)
prec = 49 <= L-1 = 52 : True
next prec = 56

table = [(2, 3), (5, 6), (12, 20), (21, 25), (28, 28), (35, 48), (53, 55)]
holes = [(4, 4), (7, 11), (26, 27), (29, 34), (49, 52)]
```

The result is correct:
- it gives the gap (4,4) between (2,3) and (5,6)
- there's no gap between (12,20) and (21,25)
- value 28 present in (28,28) isn't in any gap

OP says that the intervals are non over-lapping and sorted.
However, the test `if prec<=L-1` is mandatory, otherwise contiguous intervals give an error:
without this test, the result would contain
`....., (7, 11), (21, 20), (26, 27), .......`

.

It happens that with this mandatory test, the following lists of intervals
`[[ 8,  9],[14, 18],[18, 32]]`
`[[8, 9], [14, 18], [19, 20], [16, 21], [23, 32]]`
that are over-lapping (not what OP says)
and that would give error without the test,
don't produce any error in fact.

The rule for a list of intervals to give a correct list of gaps with my above code is that the intervals must be sorted along the second element.

.

Replacing `yield (prec,L-1)` with `yield range(prec,L)` will gives the gaps as ranges.

Replacing `yield (prec,L-1)` with `holes.append((prec,L-1))`, for example, allows to write the code without a function.

Comment: Storing `prec` in the generator makes for a nice readable solution. You don't need the `else` clause, just move `prec = b` after the `if` block. The OP now says the pairs are sorted and non-overlapping, so you don't need to test for those cases. But I think it probably makes sense to suppress "empty holes" like (4, 4) and (22, 22) from the output if they can occur.

Comment: Ah ! you are right for the line ``prec = b``. Instrcutions ``a += 1`` and  ``b += 1`` can also be removed if ``prec = b + 1``. - But for (4,4) and (22,22), it's correct: they mean gaps of only one number. - I imagined other solutions, based on ouputs directly being ranges. - Thank you for your comment

Comment: If you want to avoid modifying table, one way is to just set `prec = None` initially  and test for it in the loop

Comment: You are right about the holes with one entry. For an empty hole the table would look like `[[16, 21], [22, 32]]` and the hole would look like `[22, 21]`.

Comment: @gnibbler raaaaa.... after many numerous edits, I finally ended up to a final answer. I didn't retain your idea of using ``None``, because comparing ``None`` and a number doesn't works, and I didn't want to add a test that would have been useful only at first step. I got the idea of initializing ``first prec = intervals[0][1] == first H`` that is always strictly superior to the first value ``intervals[0][0] - 1 == first L -1`` since ``L`` and ``H`` are always so that ``H >= L`` then ``first H > first L-1`` , then ``first prec > first L-1`` then ``first prec <= first L -1`` is always false.

Comment: @gnibbler The above trick for the first value of ``prec`` is possible only because there's a test in the algorithm. It happens that this test is mandatory if we don't want that ``...(12, 20), (21, 25)...`` to give a gap ``(21, 20)``. So all is justified, even for non-overlapping lists of intervals. The lists of intervals need only to be sorted based on their second element. I did several tests with various values for the first interval, it seems that my code is robustly correct for all cases, given this condition on the second elements.

Comment: There was a bug with the initial interval being adjacent to the second which I have fixed with adding onet to the initial prec. (e.g. table =   [(2,3),(4,6),(12,20),(21,25),(28,28),(35,48),(53,55)]).

Comment: @WilliamKF I don't understand what you say. I see that you replaced ``prec = intervals[0][1]`` with ``prec = intervals[0][1] + 1`` but I wonder why you think it's necessary. Without the ``+ 1`` I get ``[(7, 11), (26, 27), (29, 34), (49, 52)]`` as a result for the list you gave ``[(2,3),(4,6),(12,20),(21,25....``. Isn't it a desired result ?

Comment: @eyquem, Yes that is the desired result, but when I ran it I got an extra bogus value in the result without the +1: [(3, 3) (7, 11) (26, 27) (29, 34) (49, 52)].

Comment: @WilliamKF I'm perplex. I copied the code in my answer (with the +1 you added), I pasted it in IDLE, I removed the +1 after ``prec = intervals[0][1]``, I copied/pasted your list in your comment ``[(2,3),(4,6),(12,20),(21,25),(.....``, I ran the program, and I got what you say is the desired result ``[(7, 11), (26, 27), (29, 34), (49, 52)]`` , not `` [(3, 3) (7, 11) (26, 27) (29, 34) (49, 52)]``

Comment: Are you looking at the yielded result?  If you don't add one to initial prec, prec is 3, then the first iteration with L == 4 gets to the if 3 <= 4 - 1 which is true so it yields prec, 4 - 1 and gives the first (3, 3) incorrectly.

Comment: @WilliamKF Anyway, bigger is the value added to ``prec = intervals[0][1]``, the more ``first prec`` will be greater than ``first L``, so it is very important. But I don't understand your evoquation of a bogus.

Comment: @WilliamKF Oh I got the reason of problem: my code is erroneous in my answer when it displays the values to show the process. It must be ``% (prec,L-1,prec<=L-1)``, not ``% (prec,L-1,prec<=L)`` . I forgot the ``-1`` at the end. But it effectively is in the test, so the algorithm is good and gives good result, even with ``first prec = intervals[0][1]`` ! (:-(o)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `tuple` constructor with a generator expression:

```
lower = tuple(x - 1 for x in lower)
upper = tuple(x + 1 for x in upper)
```

Comment: to provide the result required by the OP the operators and the slicing have to be changed in this way: `holes = zip([x + 1 for x in upper][:-1], [x - 1 for x in lower][1:])`

Comment: Yes, you can do it in one line, but I think it looks cleaner separated into multiple lines. (That's just my opinion).

Comment: sorry nneonneo my comment was related to returning the expected answer, not to put it in one line (that was just for easiness, being only a comment). I edited my comment to clarify this aspect (see also ogzd comment)

Comment: @nneonneo @furins Clicking ENTER just after ``zip([x + 1 for x in upper][:-1],`` will make the suite appear at the next line (pleasing to nneonneo) while it remains a one-liner in essence (pleasing to furins)

Answer (score 6):

You can also just work these out in a single list comprehension:

```
holes = [(table[i][1]+1, table[i+1][0]-1) for i in range(len(table)-1)]
```

Comment: Ah I wrote the same line, but forgot about him wanting to remove the first element of lower and the last element of upper. I think this solution is much more pythonic.

Comment: @ogzd, yes that seems to be what is wanted now there is an example

Comment: to be even more precise the answer should be `holes = zip([x + 1 for x in upper][:-1], [x - 1 for x in lower][1:])` (a list of lists) in order to match the given example... ;)

Comment: @gnibbler Hello, gnibbler, did you see my answer ? I'd like to know what you think about it.